# Conditional type which depends on a value and includes null

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a conditional type for different user profiles but it doesn't work as I expect.

I have an interface for user

```
export interface User {
  profile: UserProfile
 // other props
}
```

`UserProfile` might be different and depends on type

```
export type UserProfile = UnknownProfile | DentistProfile | VendorProfile

export interface UnknownProfile extends UserCommonProfile<null> {}
export interface DentistProfile extends UserCommonProfile<'DENTIST'> { dentistDetails: DentistDetails }
export interface VendorProfile extends UserCommonProfile<'BROKER'> { vendorDetails: VendorDetails }
```

And some common types

```
export type UserTypes = 'DENTIST' | 'BROKER'

export interface UserCommonProfile<T extends UserTypes> {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  email: string
  type: T | null
}
```

There are a few problems:

1. If `type === null` it's possible to add any other fields as `dentistDetails` or `vendorDetails` or all together at the same time. It's not so important but anyway
2. I have a function to update profile

```
public async update(profile: UserProfile): Promise<void> {
  const user = await this.getUser()
    
  switch (profile.type) {
    case 'DENTIST':
      return this._firestore
        .doc<UserDocument>(`users/${user.id}`)
        .update({
          profile: { ...user.profile, type: 'DENTIST', dentistDetails: profile.dentistDetails },
        })
    case 'BROKER':
      // ...
  }
}
```

Here I have an error `Property 'dentistDetails' does not exist on type 'UnknownProfile'`. Also I should add `type: 'DENTIST'` to identify object type, but seems it makes sense.

How to create conditional types in this case?

Comment: What TypeScript version are you using? Do you use `strict` mode? I tested your code in TS Playground and with only one minor change it works fine (at least if I understood you correctly). The change I introduced is to move ` | null` from `type` property to the `UserTypes` union. Check [the playground here](https://shorturl.at/wzF04)

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that doesn't use private or third-party code; anything in the example should be native to TypeScript, or properly declared.  Or, if the question actually *depends* on third-party code, you might want to tag the question accordingly (firestore)?  Right now the code as-is [causes errors in my IDE](https://tsplay.dev/w1QKyw) that are mostly unrelated to what you're asking about.  Which makes it harder to make suggestions.

Comment: @arkus you are right about `strict` mode. It was `false`. I changed it to `true` and all worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use generic types which is not the use case and complicate things. Here is what you can do:

Union all user types in one type:

```
type UserTypes = "UNKNOWN" | "DENTIST" | "BROKER";
```

Define the user common profile interface and add a type property:

```
interface UserCommonProfile {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  type: UserTypes;
}
```

Extend the common profile and define different variations with additional properties as needed:

```
interface UnknownProfile extends UserCommonProfile {
  type: "UNKNOWN";
  sampleProperty: "sampleProperty";
}

interface DentistProfile extends UserCommonProfile {
  type: "DENTIST";
  dentistDetails: "dentistDetails";
}

interface VendorProfile extends UserCommonProfile {
  type: "BROKER";
  vendorDetails: "vendorDetails";
}
```

Union all variations in one type and start using it:

```
type UserProfile = UnknownProfile | DentistProfile | VendorProfile;

interface User {
    profile: UserProfile;
    // other props
}
```

Now, you can use the switch case safely:

```
public async update(profile: UserProfile): Promise<void> {
    switch (profile.type) {
        case "DENTIST":
            console.log(profile.dentistDetails);
            return;
        case "BROKER":
            console.log(profile.vendorDetails);
            return;
    }
}
```

Or you can better define assertion functions for variations like this:

```
const isUnknownProfile = (profile: UserProfile): profile is UnknownProfile => profile.type === "UNKNOWN";
const isDentistProfile = (profile: UserProfile): profile is DentistProfile => profile.type === "DENTIST";
const isVendorProfile = (profile: UserProfile): profile is VendorProfile => profile.type === "BROKER";
```

And then use if conditions to check:

```
if (isDentistProfile(profile)) {
    console.log(profile.dentistDetails);
} else if (isVendorProfile(profile)) {
    console.log(profile.vendorDetails);
}
```

Finally make sure you read [the typescript handbook section about `Narrowing`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) to understand better.